# Cannot open fragment from another fragment - No view found for id 0x7f0e0084

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, view, fragment

How to open fragment from another fragment?
When I try to open EditNote fragment from another ShowNotes fragment and I get this error.

```
No view found for id 0x7f0e0084 (com.example.lalala.notepad:id/container_frame_layout) for fragment EditNote{3005d06 #1 id=0x7f0e0084}
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1293)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
```

ShowNotes.java is the fragment from which I want to open another fragment

```
public class ShowNotes extends Fragment {
private ListView lv;
ArrayList<Note> arrayList;
private View view;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_show_notes, container, false);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Note n = new Note("Example", "It's just an example");

    arrayList.add(n);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    NoteAdapter adapter = new NoteAdapter(view.getContext(), arrayList);
    lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.notes_listview);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            EditNote fragment2=new EditNote();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_frame_layout,fragment2);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
}}
```

EditNote.java is now an almost empty fragment, it just inflates the view.

```
public class EditNote extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_edit_note, container, false);
    return view;
}}
```

activity_edit_note.xml contains framelayout into which I want to inflate the view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: `Cannot open fragment from another fragment`. I think you should read the error message again.

Answer (score 0):

You are using getSupportFragmentManager not getFragmentManager()

Try changing these lines

```
EditNote fragment2=new EditNote();
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_frame_layout,fragment2);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

to

```
 EditNote fragment2=new EditNote();
     this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.container_frame_layout, fragment2,TAG_FRAGMENT)
     .addToBackStack(null)
     .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to initiate your viewPager before you use it in Fragment Transaction.

ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container_frame_layout, fragment2);